# Changes in site by Elementor page builder into desktop version and it does not show into the mobile version?

Tags: wordpress, caching, plugins, browser-cache, elementor

Changes in website, using elementor page builder is not showing properly in mobile version.

Answer (score 0):

if these changes are not showing in mobile by CSS or JS (frontend), no problem for caching.
if these changes are not showing in mobile by php (backend), this can be caching issue if you dont seperate mobile cache and desktop cache

Comment: some icons are not showing, and the previous site which I have updated is not showing. updated one is not showing.

Comment: did you separate css for mobile and desktop?

Comment: right now, I am not developing the site mobile responsive.